# Boundary value of a homeomorphism

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Assume that $f$ is a homeomorphism of the unit disk onto itself. Assume also that $f$ has a continuous extension up to the boundary. It seems that $f$ is monotonous at the boundary, but I need a reference.

Comment: what do you mean by "monotonous at the boundary"?

Comment: @YCor $f(e^{it})=e^{i \phi(t)}$ for some monotonous $\phi:[0,2\pi]\to [0,2\pi]$

Comment: But this is true for every self-homeomorphism of the unit circle... well, this is the same since every self-homeomorphism of the circle extends to a self-homeomorphism of the disc, but the proof doesn't use this fact. It's a direct lifting argument.

Comment: @YCor, I dont understand you. I ask whether the boundary mapping is monotonous. Probably this is just topological argument.

Comment: OK, I now see, I was too hasty, the continuous map induced on the boundary is not necessarily injective.

Comment: Just an idea: Maybe it is true that for $r$ close enough to $1$, the composite $rS^n\rightarrow D^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}\rightarrow S^n$ is a homeomorphism (The first map is $f$ and the second the canonical projection). If that is true, then your map is approximable by homeomorphisms. If I recall correctly, this implies that the map is simple, e.g. all point inverses are contractible. That should be equivalent to your condition monotonous.

Answer (score 3):

Another idea: Let $D$ be the open unit disc and suppose that $f$ is the extension to the closure of $D$. Let $f(a)=f(b)$ for two distinct points $a$, $b$ from the boundary of $D$. Then consider segment $A$ joining $a$ and $b$, which cuts the open disc into two open sets $U$ and $V$. It follows that $f(A)$ is a simple closed curve. By the Jordan curve theorem, there are two open disjoint domains $U'$ and $V'$ in $D\setminus f(A)$ (and e.g. $U'=f(U)$ is the one which is bounded by $f(A)$). The boundary of $U$ is mapped onto the boundary of $U'$ by continuity of $f$. Hence an arc on the boundary of $D$ joining $a$ and $b$ which is in the closure of $B$ is mapped to $f(a)=f(b)$.
Consequently point preimages of $f$ are connected and hence $f$ is monotone.